# Clicking on link displays enlarged text box with results

Tags: php

I am trying to return an array however I keep getting the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: arr

I'm not sure where I went wrong?

```
<?php
$result = 1;
function getAns($result){
    if($result == 1){
        $arr = array("1"=>"A","2"=>"B");
    }
    elseif($result == 2){
        $arr = array("1"=>"D","2"=>"E");
    }
    return $arr;
}
getAns($result);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the returned value:

```
$result = 1;
function getAns($result){
    if($result == 1){
        $arr = array("1"=>"A","2"=>"B");
    }
    elseif($result == 2){
        $arr = array("1"=>"D","2"=>"E");
    }
    return $arr;
}
$arr = getAns($result); // use returned value : add '$arr ='
print_r($arr);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [1] => A
    [2] => B
)
```

Comment: oh haha what a silly mistake, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Zestyy99 You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAns($i){
    $arr = array('', array('1'=>'A','2'=>'B'), array('1'=>'D','2'=>'E'));
    return $arr[$i];
}
```

Comment: again, please avoid code-only answers, always add some explanations. Also, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer